# Is this combination of convex functional is still convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $u$, $v\in C_c^\infty$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ is open bounded, smooth boundary. We also assume that $0\leq v\leq 1$.

Define
$$
F(u,v):=\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2v^2dx.
$$
Do we have $F(u,v)$ is convex? i.e., for any $0<t<1$, do we have
$$
F(tu_1+(1-t)u_2, tv_1+(1-t)v_2)\leq tF(u_1,v_1)+(1-t)F(u_2,v_2)
$$

I know for instance that the product of two nonnegative, nondecreasing convex function is convex, but it does not apply to this case since $\nabla u$ is not always non-negative.

Comment: $(x,y)\mapsto x^2y^2$ is not convex. $(1,0)\mapsto 0$, $(0,1)\mapsto 0$, but $(\frac12,\frac12)\mapsto \frac1{16}>0$.

Comment: @Rahul hmm, you are right.

Comment: The same logic applies to your problem: Choose $u_1,v_1$ and $u_2,v_2$ such that such that $\nabla u_1\ne0$, $v_1=0$, and $\nabla u_2=0$, $v_2\ne0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in a comment by [Rahul](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571342/is-this-combination-of-convex-functional-is-still-convex#comment3201256_1571342), this functional is not convex. Indeed, let $B_1,B_2$ be two disjoint closed balls in $\Omega$ and let $u,v$ be bump functions with support $B_1,B_2$ respectively. Then $F(u,v)=F(v,u)=0$, but 
$$F\left(\frac{u+v}{2},\frac{u+v}{2}\right) = F(u/2,u/2)+F(v/2,v/2)>0$$
showing that $F$ is not convex.

$F$ is *separately convex* in each variable, though.